# Will your income be haram if you didn't do the work properly?

Tags: halal-haram

My father is a government employee.His job is to look after a big water pump for a certain period of time.Such as 8 hours daily.sometimes he put one of my family memebers in his post tok look after the pump instead of him and comes home.
Is my father's income halal?As the pump is being taken care of even when he is not there.